# How to get SQL Over Clause to Work in a Condition SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my problem:

I need to get the first result in my database for each matching row.  I am getting numerous rows.

Original Query returns more than one row per custid:

```
   select distinct b.custid, name   
        FROM  mth_Charge_Records  a   
        join mth_header b on b.id = a.headerid
```

So, in order to get the first row, I figured I would number them and just take the ones numbered 1.  So here is that query:

```
  select distinct b.custid, name,   
         count(custid) OVER (order by custid rows unbounded preceding)   as custcount
     FROM  mth_Charge_Records  a   
     join mth_header b on b.id = a.headerid
```

It works and the row numbers are counted off.   So, I tried to add custcount as a condition and it fails:

```
  select distinct b.custid, name,   
         count(custid) OVER (order by custid rows unbounded preceding)   as custcount
     FROM  mth_Charge_Records  a   
     join mth_header b on b.id = a.headerid     
     where custcount = 1   <<--- Added this line
```

Now I am getting the error that custcount is an invalid column.

Any help or suggestions owuld be appreciated.  Thanks so much :)

Comment: can you please tag RDMBS you are using ?

Comment: use row_number() function instead of count ... you can insert your record into temp table and then select only those with rownum 1 or use CTE

Comment: What is the "first row"? That's where you need to start - with clearly defined requirements. `custcount` isn't a valid column because SQL Server hasn't processed that part of the query (naming the columns) before it's being asked to use that name. There are several ways around it, but which is best depends on those requirements.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at [SELECT (Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql). You'll notice that the `SELECT` portion of the statement is evaluated **after** the `WHERE`. This means you can't refer to columns that are in the `SELECT` by alias.

And you may, also, have noticed you can't use Window Functions within the `WHERE` clause. YOu could use a CTE, but i think, perhaps, what you'll actually want is a `HAVING` clause. Thus:

```
SELECT mt.custid,
       [name]
FROM mth_Charge_Records mCR
     JOIN mth_header mt on mCR.headerid = mt.id
GROUP BY mt.custid,
         [name]
HAVING COUNT(mt.custid) = 1;
```

Edit: `COUNT` was a bit of a misguidance after rereading. YOu'll want a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT mt.custid,
           [name],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mt.custid) AS RN
    FROM mth_Charge_Records mCR
     JOIN mth_header mt on mCR.headerid = mt.id)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Reading inbetween the lines of the OP, the `COUNT` was a bit of a misguide. I've updated.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt at `row_number()` would return an arbitrary row.  If that is all you want, why not use aggregation?

```
select h.custid, max(crname)  
from mth_Charge_Records cr join
     mth_header h
     on h.id = cr.headerid;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this 
Select a.*
From ( 
select distinct b.custid, name,   
         count(custid) OVER (order by custid rows unbounded preceding)   as custcount
     FROM  mth_Charge_Records  a   
     join mth_header b on b.id = a.headerid 
) a    
     where a.custcount = 1
```